# Checkbox enable when Combox indicator is selected as yes(vb.net)

Tags: vb.net

I have a indicator in the comboBox and a checkbox, I need to enable the checkbox when the indicator field is selected as yes and disable the checkbox when the field is selected as no

Please help add the code in the combo box to enable checkbox property

Answer (score 0):

You have several different options, but perhaps the simplest would be to check the value of the ComboBox in the SelectedIndexChanged event to toggle the Checked property of the CheckBox. Here is a quick example:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    CheckBox1.Checked = ComboBox1.Text = "Yes"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response,

Comment: so I have a drop down box in my combox(the name of that box is change_in)

Comment: if the drop down is selected as yes I want the checkbox to be enabled and if it is selected as no I want the check box to be disabled

Comment: @Jessi, you have already been shown what to do.  Why are you explaining what you need to do when you've already been shown how to do it?

Comment: The reason I am explaining is, I dont want the checkbox to be checked when the dropdown is Yes, I just want it to be enabled and I want it to be disabled(show as graded out) when the dropdown is No

Comment: You have an event to put your code in. Try an If...Else...End If to set the appropriate property of the check box.

Comment: So change the line 'CheckBox1.Checked = ComboBox1.Text = "Yes"' to 'CheckBox1.Enabled = ComboBox1.Text = "Yes"`